# How go full screen with QWebEngineView (PySide2) without crash?

Tags: python, pyside2, qwebengineview

**Has anyone managed to get PySide2 (v5.12) successfully go full screen on QWebEngineView  via fullScreenRequested command?**

Every time I am executing the command Python 3.72 crashes. I also tried with 3.6 and receive similar result.

Screenshot

[image]

PyQt5.11.3 on the other hand seems to work fine.

Did I find a bug with PySide2 and QWebEngineView And Fullscreen?!

Thank you guys :)

Running this (swap PySide2 for PyQt5) fullscreenrequest under PyQt5.11.3 works.
It seems PySide2 either has a bug or the command changed.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings


app = QApplication([])
view = QWebEngineView()
view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True)
view.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(lambda request: request.accept())
view.load(QUrl("https://youtube.com"))
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: What is the point of reporting this here? Have posted an issue to the pyside bug tracker?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or PySide2 is working differently. Is anyone able to confirm? Cheers